# set text for javafx.scene.text.Text through css

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I need to store entire node properties in css for any JavaFX element or mainly
for javafx.scene.text.Text or javafx.scene.shape.

For Text I'm not sure how to set text value though css. Is it possible?

I need to store all properties in css so that I can easily recreate same element with applied properties
with help of this css.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official CSS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text) nodes this is not possible, there does not appear to be an equivalent of the web [CSS content attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) which I believe you require. I find JavaFX CSS limited e.g. does not support most CSS layout properties, width, height etc.

The available properties are as follows plus those the -fx-font-* properties.

- -fx-font   Font.DEFAULT    inherits
- -fx-font-smoothing-type  [ gray | lcd ]  gray
- -fx-strikethrough       false
- -fx-text-alignment   [ left | center | right | justify ] left    inherits
- -fx-text-origin  [ baseline | top | bottom ] baseline
- -fx-underline

If you're really desperate, you could create a custom subclass of Text which supported it using [CSS API to support custom UI Controls](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/CSS+API+to+support+custom+UI+Controls). This looks like quite a task though.

Comment: That's correct. In JavaFX, CSS is used to *style* the nodes in the scenegraph (i.e. to change their appearance). Layout is managed by FXML and/or Java, and logical processing (processing user input, etc) is managed by Java. This is a deliberate design to separate these concerns and provide the best-suited technology in each case. Note that their is some cross-over of concerns: for example you can set the min/pref/max size of any [`Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)(includes all controls) with css.

Comment: As @Adam and @James_D said, there is no CSS property that can be used to set `Text` content. You can, however, create a subclass of `Text` that adds a styleable property `content` and binds `textProperty` to `contentProperty`.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. In the end I had to just recreate Text or other nodes from stored css/json string. So I made workaround in handling of this string itself because extending Text would add lot of work for getting a small thing done and would be useful for case of Text node only.

Comment: The view that changing the content of a Node is not styling is outdated IMHO.  With CSS I can provide patterns and shapes, but not say a specific Unicode glyph for a specific type of arrow that Unicode provides for example.